# Console application only sending first 46 characters in a POST request

Tags: c#, php, post

I am building a console application that gathers some data and then sends it to a php page through a POST request. This is my C# code:

```
HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/log.php");
Request.Method = "POST";
Request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
string PostData = "data=" + UserOutput;
Request.ContentLength = PostData.Length;

StreamWriter stOut = new StreamWriter(Request.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
stOut.Write(PostData);
stOut.Close();
```

And the PHP page (log.php):

```
<?php

file_put_contents('log.txt', $_POST['data']);

?>
```

Note I am only using `file_put_contents` to test if everything works OK, it is not what I want to end up doing.

The length of the post data to send is over 2,000 characters long, and the correct content length is returned by `Request.ContentLength = PostData.Length;`, so that's not the problem. But whenever I try this it is only sending the first 46 characters of my POST data.

I do have to admit at this point that I copied most of the code, as I am not very experienced in C#.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the 47th character "&" by any chance? You've claimed that your data is URL-encoded, but you haven't done any URL-encoding in the code you've provided. If there's an "&" that would indicate to PHP that it was about to accept a new form parameter...

One way to verify this (apart from using `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`) would be to use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to see what's *actually* going on at the network level.

Comment: Aha, I never actually thought of that. That is the problem and I'll make sure to UrlEncode it from now on. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The `Close()` should handle it, but you may want to try a `.Flush()` just before that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only sending one big blob of data, it would be a better strategy to omit the `Content-type` header and make `PostData == UserOutput`.

You could then save it with

```
$s = fopen("php://input", "r");
file_put_contents('log.txt', $s);
```